# Code only works on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsfiddle, jsbin

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375253/color-shades-responsive-to-number-of-divs/) I asked, how I can generate shades of one color responsive to the number of div's. @DonJuwe came up with a perfectly working solution and demo: http://jsbin.com/xakifequ/1/edit
[image: Source code in JSBin]

However when I'm trying to use the code from the jsfiddle or [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xakifequ/1/edit) it just doesn't work.
So I downloaded the source code from JSBin, opened the .html-file and what I got was this: [image: What happens when downloading it]

Can someone please explain me, why this happens?

Comment: jQuery isn't loaded because you include jQuery without a protocol (e.g. http) in the `head`. The browser automatically looks for `file://` and there is no jQuery

Comment: oh and your console should display a clear error..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missed `http:` in the jQuery source link. if you using `online resource` you should follow the `url's protocol`. Other wise browser will search it from local. in this way you just confused your browser... So only it happens... :D

you should use...

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

instead of

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

As per snapshot, You are using

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

Replace it with

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
```

You are using protocol less Urls, i.e. `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`, When you open a your html file like `file://` then jQuery is not loaded thus desired result is not achieved.

However, if you test your html file like `http://localhost/yourfile.html` you will get the desired result.

Note: Use `//` instead of `http://` when you want to inherit the protocol from the page

Comment: Wow! The big impact of details…